# Jquery - use "starts with" matching with remote datasource

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Wondering how I can switch the following code to use a remote data source instead of a local array. This code changes the matching to "starts with"

```
    $("#input").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(req, responseFn) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
        var a = $.grep( group_members_array, function(item){
            return matcher.test(item.value);
            });
        responseFn( a );
    }
});
```

Comment: You say nothing about your `autocomplete` function. I've re-tagged the question assuming jQuery UI's, please correct it if I'm wrong.

Comment: This should be done in your server-side code. Are you using a remote data source that you don't have control over?

Comment: @ Álvaro, yes sorry. I should have put auto complete in the title and tags.

Comment: @Andrew, My problem is that it's not matching against the entire username even tho that's what's in the value of my object. It's matching on the last name because that's what the query has in the "where" clause. I could change the query. Although I was hoping to avoid that.